# why unmarshal make the type of object changed in golang

Tags: go, interface, unmarshalling

I want to write a mockData method which can accept several types of parameter and return correspond objects based on its json data. The code as below:

```
func MockData(jsonPath string,v interface{})(interface{},error){
    var ret interface{}
    data,_ := ioutil.ReadFile(jsonPath)    
    switch v.(type) {
    case Req:
        ret = Req{}
        fmt.Printf("\n===before Unmarshal==%T===\n",ret)
        err = json.Unmarshal(data,&ret) 
        if err!=nil{...}
        fmt.Printf("======after unmarshal===%T\n",ret)
    case ...
    default:
        fmt.Printf("error===not match")
   }
   return ret,err
}
```

However, it panics when I use it. The code as below:

```
func main(){
    reqJsonPath := /xx/yy/req.json
    obj,err:=test.MockData(jsonFile,Req{})
    if err!=nil{...}
    require := obj.(Req) //panic cant []interface{} to Req
}
```

and the output of MockData is:

```
===before Unmarshal==Req===
======after unmarshal===[]interface{}
```

the type of object **changed after unmarshal**. and some more strange is that if I replace:

```
ret = Req{}
```

with

```
ret = &Req{}
```

the output will be same as below:

```
===before Unmarshal==*Req===
======after unmarshal===*Req
```

To reproduce the problem more conveniently I give the Require struct as below:

```
type Req []*Ele
type Ele struct {
   ID   int 
   Level int   
}
```

**summary**:

1. Can I achieve expected function which produces different types of objects based on its json and type?
2. Why does the type of object changed after unmarshal, and why it not changed after I add &?

Comment: The variable `ret` is of type `interface{}` and that type is used to unmarshal into. Reflection is complicated and your Printfs do not work like you expect them to. Read the blog post Laws of Reflection. You must actually unmarshal into a common.Require (instead of a empty interface) so move the variable decl into the type switch.

Comment: Where is `common.Require` defined?

Comment: @Flimzy oh, In order to simplified question I replace common.Require with Req, I will update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I achieve expected function which produces different types of objects based on its json and type?

```
func MockData(filename string, v interface{}) (interface{}, error) {

    data, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
    switch t := v.(type) {
    case Req:
        // t at this point is a Req{}
        err := json.Unmarshal(data, &t)
        return t, err
    }
    return nil, errors.New("unknown type")
}
```

I don't really know your motivation why you you need to pass an actual struct rather than a pointer. [Check this demonstration](https://play.golang.org/p/M9TRguljMe_O)

> Why does the type of object changed after unmarshal, and why it not changed after I add &?

When you unmarshal using `&ret` where `ret` is an interface, you are getting the address of the interface. Hence, `json.Unmarshal()` will see that the backing data is a interface rather than a pointer to a struct. The default data type that `json.Unmarshal()` will use is `map[string]interface{}` for objects and `[]interface{}` for arrays.

Now if you unmarshal using `ret` where `ret` is `&Req{}`, `json.Unmarshal()` will check that the backing data is a `struct`, hence it can do it's unmarshaling using the struct's fields.

**Edit**:

You seem to be confused by *pointer to an interface* which is different to an *interface which has a pointer*. Try this code and you'll see the difference.

```
var x interface{} = Req{}
var y interface{} = &x
var z interface{} = &Req{}

fmt.Printf("%T\n", y)
fmt.Printf("%T\n", z)
```

Remember that interfaces are just normal values and they also take memory. Now if you take an address of that memory, you get the pointer to the interface rather than the pointer to the data the interface is referring to.

Comment: if I unmarshal using `ret`, the `&ret` is the address of interface as well. why `json.Unmarshal()` will check the backing data is `struct`?

Comment: Because it is a pointer to a struct rather than a pointer to an interface.

Answer (score 0):

1. Can I achieve expected function which produces different types of objects based on its json and type?

Yes, but you'll have to convert it back using a type assertion at the calling end ie

```
  MyFoo:=MockData("foo.json", Foo{}).(Foo)
```

(or have multiple `return ret.(Foo)` `return ret.(Bar)` in the func)

2. Why does the type of object changed after unmarshal, and why it not changed after I add &?

There are some helpful comments in the top of the Unmarshal source 
namely

```
// To unmarshal JSON into a pointer, Unmarshal first handles the case of
// the JSON being the JSON literal null. In that case, Unmarshal sets
// the pointer to nil. Otherwise, Unmarshal unmarshals the JSON into
// the value pointed at by the pointer. If the pointer is nil, Unmarshal
// allocates a new value for it to point to.
```

and

```
// To unmarshal JSON into an interface value,
// Unmarshal stores one of these in the interface value:
//
//  bool, for JSON booleans
//  float64, for JSON numbers
//  string, for JSON strings
//  []interface{}, for JSON arrays
//  map[string]interface{}, for JSON objects
//  nil for JSON null
```

So in the first case you are unmarshalling into an interface value (`ret` is declared as an interface{})
In the second case there is a pointer to a struct so that's what you get